# Adding libpng to xcode

Tags: xcode, libpng

I want to add the library `libpng` to Xcode to read and write a `.png` file,
but even if I tried many recommended ways I could not do it.

Actually I have to read an image and manipulate its RGB values for my college project in C and I don't know the process of adding libraries to my IDE.

If you have any idea please help me, and maybe suggesty me if there is another useful PNG library.

Answer (score 1):

Include it via a pod. It has a pod-spec: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/3/7/8/libpng/1.6.18/libpng.podspec.json

Check this out if you don't know pod's: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I succeeded in making a podfile but the pod file gave an error that it could not read the licence so if you have an idea please share with me